# What types of administrative jobs can a faculty member get?

Tags: university, job, faculty-application, united-kingdom, administration

I am a professor of physics and just moved to the UK with my wife, who is British. I anticipate that it will take a year or so to find a faculty position matching my field of expertise. To avoid being idle during this period, I would like to apply for any possible job to be in academia.

As I checked, many administrative jobs are available in the UK universities, and the process seems quick (the interviews are normally scheduled for 2 weeks after the deadline).

Since I have worked as a department head for years with many industry collaborations, I thought I might have a chance at administrative jobs like director of small units such as enterprise, partnership, academic excellence, etc.

I understand that people with the same line of experience are rationally preferred, but I wonder if there are specific administrative jobs for which faculty experience is an advantage and the committee will be happy to consider such applications.

Comment: If this is not about the money, can’t you do some research as a visiting or sabbatical professor?

Comment: It's a slightly tangential point, but Professor of Physics is a slightly confusing job title in connection with Commonwealth countries. Are we correct in reading this as "permanent faculty with teaching experience"?

Comment: What @origimbo said - in the UK you don't *apply* for the job title of "professor", you get *awarded* the title eventually (maybe after 20 years in academia) on the basis of what you have *done* during that time. In other words, it's a very senior academic title, compared with some other countries.

Comment: @origimbo in some countries such as the US, academics who teach might be generally referred to as *professor*, but still, *professor* is not their job title (lecturer, assistant professor, adjunct professor, etc). I believe, the job title of *professor* has the same meaning, equivalent to *full professor*.

Comment: @herman -- what country were you a professor in?

Answer (score 13):

I feel this is a question that's almost better suited for [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/). My fear in your case would be that you, having been a department head previously, are seen as vastly overqualified for almost every non-leadership administrative position (and leadership positions tend to not be filled as quickly as you mention). It may appear surprising to meritocracy-oriented academics, but people are generally not prone to hire overqualified staff - motivation and job satisfaction can become issues, and they are expected to not stay on long (as you yourself also don't intend to do).

That being said, I can't help but wonder whether you have any contacts in the UK that you can activate. Maybe there is some temporary administrative role that would suit your skill set, or a temporary teaching position in courses related to your experience. To me, that seems like a more promising shot than blindly applying to regular administrative posts, and hoping that the hiring team sees your very unconventional background as a positive.

---

As a sidenote, I also wonder why you are confident that you will find a faculty position in a year unless you already have one lined up. As I understand it, senior-level hires in the UK are a pretty rare and long-running processes, and hoping for one within a year, which you then also need to win, seems to be putting a lot of eggs into a very specific basket. *If* you already have one lined up, talk to the people there about some temporary contract in the meantime.

Comment: Regarding your sidenote: One department at my university is looking for a new department head for some years already now (exchanging the substitute head every now and then) and the process might well take a few more years. Thus, I totally agree that getting a faculty position, or even one as department head, might take far longer than a year if you just start looking now.

Comment: Re: The Workplace, see [Why do companies not want to hire over qualified people?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30544/why-do-companies-not-want-to-hire-over-qualified-people)

Comment: I echo the sentiment in the final paragraph